# How to align app bar when there is back button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

In my app bar, I have a texts and Image  but every time I go to a second page, the text and image is not align to center anymore since there is back button on the left corner.

I'm just wondering how can I make it align center so that it'll look the same for every screen.

```
     appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Maxis",
              style:
                  TextStyle(fontFamily: "Raleway", fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
            ),
            Image.asset(
              "assets/images/Image.png",
              width: 30,
            ),
            Text(
              "Mobile",
              style:
                  TextStyle(fontFamily: "Raleway", fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
```

Comment: You can achieve this with Stack but perhaps someone would have a more elegant answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a row with MainAxisAlignment.center and MainAxisSize.min and centerTitle: true on the AppBar

```
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        const Text('title 1'),
        const SizedBox(width: 16),
        const Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
        const SizedBox(width: 16),
        const Text('title 2'),
      ],
    ),
    centerTitle: true,
    elevation: 6,
  ),
```